# Why does PyTorch Linear allow multiple output dimensions?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, python

PyTorch has a [Linear component](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#linear-layers) that accepts input and output dimension arguments. If you want to implement linear regression, for example, supply n input features and 1 output feature and the model will take the dot product of features (for a given observation) and weights, $xw^T$. Great!

But I'm curious, under what circumstances would the output dimension be greater than 1? Each element would receive all inputs but presumably return different a different value (unless every row of $w$ was identical.)

To my knowledge, PyTorch has proper neural network modules that include fully connected layers. So I'm not sure what purpose `Linear(n,m)` serves if fully connected layers are addressed elsewhere.

Comment: In an MLP, the hidden layers transform their input (either the raw features or the output from a previous hidden layer) to vectors (sometimes vectors of 1 element, but usually vectors of 2 or more elements). `nn.Linear` is the building block that is used in the FC layers. Handling batches of matrices (e.g. for NLP tasks such as LLMs) is an important usage, so you want to have a way to do linear transformation on each matrix in the batch, which is what `nn.Linear` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One use case I can think of is *multivariate* regression,as opposed to *multvariable* regression, the former being a model with more than 1 outcome variable, whereas the latter being a model with one outcome variable, but more than 1 input. In such a case you could use an output dimension greater than 1. For example, predicting the coordinates of multiple points in a space, or forecasting several future values of a time series simultaneously, each output neuron corresponds to one regression target.

Another case is multiclass classification, where each sample is assigned to one and only one label out of a set of more than two labels. This scenario uses an output dimension $m$ greater than 1 to represent the probabilities or scores for each of the multiple classes.